# 16 bit data from max6675 to a 8 bit PIC microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, pic

[image]I'm trying to read data from [MAX6675](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6675.pdf) with [PIC16f1937](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41364E.pdf). The bottom is my code

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ  4000000
#include <xc.h>
#include "MAX6675_header.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

volatile bool spi_rx_data_ready = false;

void __interrupt() interrupt_isr(){
    INTCONbits.GIE = 0;                         //Disable interrupt
    if(PIR2bits.BCLIF == 1){                    //Checking to see if MSSP Bus Collision interrupt is triggered
        
        PIR2bits.BCLIF = 0;                     //Reseting flag
    }
    else if(PIR1bits.SSPIF){                    //Checking to see if MSSP Interrupt is triggered
        spi_rx_data_ready = true;               //A flag to indicate the data is received
        PIR1bits.SSPIF = 0;                     //Reseting flag
    }
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;                         //Enable interrupt
}

void PORT_configuration(){
    TRISB = 0x00;
    LATB = 0;
    TRISCbits.TRISC3 = 0;                       //SCK as output
    TRISCbits.TRISC4 = 1;                       //SDI as input
    TRISCbits.TRISC5 = 0;                       //SDO as output
    TRISCbits.TRISC6 = 0;                       //SS as output
    LATCbits.LATC6 = 1;                         //SS is set to high to deselect slave
}

void SPI_Configuration(){
    SSPCON1bits.SSPEN = 0;                      //Disabling serial port
    ANSELA = 0x00;                              //Setting different PORTS as digital I/O
    ANSELB = 0x00;
    ANSELD = 0x00;
    ANSELE = 0x00;
    SSPSTATbits.SMP = 1;                        //Input data sampled at end of data output time                        
    SSPSTATbits.CKE = 1;                        //Transmit occurs on transition from Idle to active clock state
    SSPCON1bits.CKP = 0;                        //Idle state for clock is a high level
    SSPCON1bits.SSPM = 0x00;                    //SPI Master mode, clock = FOSC/4
    SSPCON1bits.SSPEN = 1;                      //Enabling serial port
    PIE1bits.SSPIE = 1;                         //MSSP Interrupt Enable bit
    PIE2bits.BCLIE = 1;                         //MSSP Bus Collision Interrupt Enable bit
}

void SPI_read(){
    unsigned char Temp1=0,Temp2=0;
    LATCbits.LATC6 = 0;
    __delay_us(0.1);                            //Wait for 100 nano seconds
    SSPBUF = 0x00;                              //Send dummy data to start communication
    while(spi_rx_data_ready == false);          //Wait for the data to be completely received
    spi_rx_data_ready = false;                  //Reset the flag
    Temp1 = SSPBUF;
    LATCbits.LATC6 = 1;
    __delay_ms(1000);                           //For better observation in PROTEUS (Remove for real_time application)
}

void main(void) {
    //Select 8MHz internal oscillator
    OSCCONbits.SCS = 0x03;              //Internal oscillator block
    OSCCONbits.IRCF = 0x0d;             //FOSC = 4MHz
    
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;                 //To enable global interrupts
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1;                //To enable peripheral interrupts
    
    //Calling for configuration functions
    PORT_configuration();
    SPI_Configuration();
    
    while(1){
        SPI_read();
    }
}
```

But the problem is that the output data of the MAX6675 is 16 bits and the microcontroller's SPI buffer is 8 bit (MAX6675 uses SPI protocol).
How can I receive the second 8 bits?

EDITED SPI_READ()

```
void SPI_read(){
    unsigned char Temp1=0,Temp2=0;
    LATCbits.LATC6 = 0;
    __delay_us(0.1);                            //Wait for 100 nano seconds
    SSPBUF = 0x00;                              //Send dummy data to start communication
    while(spi_rx_data_ready == false);          //Wait for the data to be completely received
    spi_rx_data_ready = false;                  //Reset the flag
    LATD = SSPBUF;
    SSPBUF = 0x00;                              //Send dummy data to start communication
    while(spi_rx_data_ready == false);          //Wait for the data to be completely received
    spi_rx_data_ready = false;                  //Reset the flag
    LATB = SSPBUF;
//    LATD = Temp1;
//    LATB = Temp2;
    LATCbits.LATC6 = 1;
    __delay_ms(1000);                           //For better observation in PROTEUS (Remove for real_time application)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just send dummy data twice, and receive twice, without toggling the /CS line.

The delay between the two 8 bit values is not an issue.

Comment: I edited the SPI_READ() and included it in my main question with a picture of my PROTEUS. I did as you said but in PROTEUS I'm getting wrong numbers I think.

Comment: That's a little more detail than I want to get into, but I don't think the delay_us macro accepts floating point numbers.

Comment: I deleted that delay. But I'm not getting any good result.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, Spehro is right but your timing is wrong.

[image]

This is the data that you will get from MAX6675.

[image]

As you can see from the datasheet, 100ns refers only to tCH, tCL, tCSS.

*200ns is 1 Period* and every bit comes at the rising edge of the period.
In theory, you should get 8 bit in 1600ns. After 1600ns, you should be ready to get the second part of the data.

Try 1600ns delay, I might miscalculate but just give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I could solve the problem and I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the problem is solved. The right code is as follows:

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ  4000000
#include <xc.h>
#include "MAX6675_header.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define RS LATBbits.LATB2
#define EN LATBbits.LATB3
#define D4 LATBbits.LATB4
#define D5 LATBbits.LATB5
#define D6 LATBbits.LATB6
#define D7 LATBbits.LATB7
#include "lcd.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

volatile bool spi_rx_data_ready = false;

void __interrupt() interrupt_isr(){
    INTCONbits.GIE = 0;                         //Disable interrupt
    if(PIR2bits.BCLIF == 1){                    //Checking to see if MSSP Bus Collision interrupt is triggered
        
        PIR2bits.BCLIF = 0;                     //Reseting flag
    }
    else if(PIR1bits.SSPIF){                    //Checking to see if MSSP Interrupt is triggered
        spi_rx_data_ready = true;               //A flag to indicate the data is received
        PIR1bits.SSPIF = 0;                     //Reseting flag
    }
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;                         //Enable interrupt
}

void PORT_configuration(){
    TRISB = 0x00;
    LATB = 0;
    TRISD = 0x00;
    LATD = 0;
    TRISCbits.TRISC3 = 0;                       //SCK as output
    TRISCbits.TRISC4 = 1;                       //SDI as input
    TRISCbits.TRISC5 = 0;                       //SDO as output
    TRISCbits.TRISC6 = 0;                       //SS as output
    LATCbits.LATC6 = 1;                         //SS is set to high to deselect slave
}

void SPI_Configuration(){
    SSPCON1bits.SSPEN = 0;                      //Disabling serial port
    ANSELA = 0x00;                              //Setting different PORTS as digital I/O
    ANSELB = 0x00;
    ANSELD = 0x00;
    ANSELE = 0x00;
    SSPSTATbits.SMP = 1;                        //Input data sampled at end of data output time                        
    SSPSTATbits.CKE = 1;                        //Transmit occurs on transition from Idle to active clock state
    SSPCON1bits.CKP = 0;                        //Idle state for clock is a high level
    SSPCON1bits.SSPM = 0x00;                    //SPI Master mode, clock = FOSC/4
    SSPCON1bits.SSPEN = 1;                      //Enabling serial port
    PIE1bits.SSPIE = 1;                         //MSSP Interrupt Enable bit
    PIE2bits.BCLIE = 1;                         //MSSP Bus Collision Interrupt Enable bit
}

void SPI_read(){
    int raw_value=0;
    char d[16];
    float temp=0.0;
    unsigned char Temp1=0,Temp2=0;
    LATCbits.LATC6 = 0;
    SSPBUF = 0x00;                              //Send dummy data to start communication
    while(spi_rx_data_ready == false);          //Wait for the data to be completely received
    spi_rx_data_ready = false;                  //Reset the flag
    Temp1 = SSPBUF;
    SSPBUF = 0x00;                              //Send dummy data to start communication
    while(spi_rx_data_ready == false);          //Wait for the data to be completely received
    spi_rx_data_ready = false;                  //Reset the flag
    Temp2 = SSPBUF;
    raw_value = (Temp1 << 5) | (Temp2 >> 3) ;
    temp = (float)raw_value / 4;
    LATCbits.LATC6 = 1;
    sprintf(d,"%f",temp);
    Lcd_Clear();
    Lcd_Set_Cursor(1,1);
    Lcd_Write_String(d);
}

void main(void) {
    //Select 8MHz internal oscillator
    OSCCONbits.SCS = 0x03;              //Internal oscillator block
    OSCCONbits.IRCF = 0x0d;             //FOSC = 4MHz
    
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;                 //To enable global interrupts
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1;                //To enable peripheral interrupts
    
    //Calling for configuration functions
    PORT_configuration();
    SPI_Configuration();
    Lcd_Init();    
    
    while(1){
        SPI_read();
    }
}
```

So basically, I read it twice as @SpehroPefhany said. And remove the extra bits and put it into another variable and then divide it by 4 which is supposed to give you the temperature in centigrade.

Comment: Any body knows why we have to divide the result by 4?

Comment: You should the datasheet of the  part MA6675 very carefully. On top of first page: General Description
The MAX6675 performs cold-junction compensation and
digitizes the signal from a type-K thermocouple. The data
is output in a 12-bit resolution, SPI-compatible, read-only
format.
This converter resolves temperatures to 0.25°C, allows
readings as high as +1024°C, and exhibits thermocouple
accuracy of 8 LSBs for temperatures ranging from 0°C to
+700°C. Result is given as a multiple of 0.25 °C, after a divison by 4 you get a multiple of 1 °C with a fractional part of two bits.